# Permanent Formatting - TRUE or FALSE

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to permanently apply conditional formatting/custom format on all spreadsheets including the new I open.

If the cell value is TRUE, highlight in Green
If the cell value is FALSE, highlight in Red

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make any changes you wish to the default template. Just google "make changes to blank template in excel" or see i.e. here

https://exceljet.net/how-to-set-a-default-template-in-excel